# Как лучше организовать связи сущностей Рецепт и Ингредиент

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Есть две сущности: Рецепт и Ингредиент. В базе таблицы заданы следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse_schema.ingredients
(
    id   BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE warehouse_schema.recipes
(
    id               BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ingredient_id    BIGINT REFERENCES warehouse_schema.ingredients (id),
    ingredient_count INT NOT NULL
);
```

На уровне объектной модели мое видение следующее:

Ингредиент:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "warehouse_schema", name = "ingredients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
```

Рецепт:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "warehouse_schema", name = "recipes")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "ingredient_count")
    Integer ingredientCount;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;
```

Также я использую DTO:

```
public class RecipeRequest {
    Long id;
    Integer ingredientCount;
    List<Long> ingredientIDs = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class IngredientRequest {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

Из моей объектной модели вытекает проблема,я не знаю как задавать ingredientCount. Так как в контроллер я должен передавать массив Id получается невозможным задать каждому из Id свой ingredientCount. Как бы вы организовали связь между сущностями для комфортного их использования? Допускаю что стоит переделать не только объектную модель,но и модель в базе

Comment: Думаю надо перейти к many to many и количество вместе с Id сущностей указывать в третьей таблице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, я правильно понял задачу и проблемы.
Постараюсь описать как бы я организовал связи для комфортной работы.

#### Лично мне не хватает сущностей, для того чтобы упаковать все данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы чуть разделил ингредиенты и добавил пару новых сущностей.

- **Продукт**
  Описывает непосредственный пищевой продукт.
  Его можно вынести отдельно, чтобы не заполнять 3000 раз соль в каждом новом рецепте и не хранить ее название в каждом ингредиенте.
  В будущем туда можно добавить иллюстрацию, описание, энергетическую ценность продукта или ещё что-нибудь.
  Также можно будет красиво выводить на странице состав блюда с иллюстрациями и автоматически подсчитывать энергетическую ценность блюда.
  Хотя если честно, то разделил я их исключительно интуитивно, поскольку по семантике пищевой продукт и ингредиент это разные вещи.
- **Единицу измерения**
  Стоит отметить, что в рецептах количество того или иного продукта указывается по-разному:

  - 1 щепотка соли
  - 0.5 стакана муки
  - 500 мл. воды
  - 100 гр. сыра
  - 1 столовая ложка подсолнечного масла
  - луковица 1 шт.
  - и т.д.

  Можно все это и в Enum засунуть, но если сделать сущность, то можно будет все это дело редактировать (*а этот список, поверьте мне, будет активно пополняться в реальном приложении...одни только американские меры длины и весов чего стоят*) и также с отдельным классом можно будет приводить одни единицы измерения к другим и делать прочие ништяки.

#### Где хранить количество

Количество продукта я бы наоборот перенёс в ингредиенты.
Теперь они у нас описывают не просто пищевые продукты, а составляющие части блюда и теперь не грех там же указывать количество того или иного продукта с указанием единицы измерения.
Конкретный нгредиент у нас "принадлежит" одному конкретному рецепту, поэтому я не вижу причин городить какие-то еще дополнительные сущности и связи.
И не вижу причин, которые бы мне помешали хранить количество в ингредиентах.

#### Что в итоге

Получается какая-то такая штука...

Product

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "warehouse_schema", name = "products")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Unit

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "warehouse_schema", name = "units")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Unit {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Ingredient

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "warehouse_schema", name = "ingredients")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Float quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    private Unit unit;

}
```

Recipe

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "warehouse_schema", name = "recipes")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    // вот этому по-моему здесь не место
    // @Column(name = "ingredient_count")
    // Integer ingredientCount;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    // ...
```

Я отталкивался от вашего примера.
*Если Вам где-то понравились мои идеи, то остальные поля можете добавить "по-вкусу".*
В ответе они были бы лишними ибо меня о них никто не спрашивал.

---

На схеме это бы выглядело так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нравится ваша идея,в особенности тем что в ней отсутствуют связи ManyToMany

Comment: @SmetanaPoAktsii, Спасибо. Если будут вопросы - оставляйте комментарии.